# serializer import error in django rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
#serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
class CommunitysStaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      role = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,default='management')
      community = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
      user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)  



#views.py

from rest_framework.response import Response
from admindashboard.serializers import CommunitysStaffSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])

def Communitystaff(request,pk=None):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CommunitysStaffSerializer(data = request.data)
    
        if serializer.is_valid():
            Staff = CommunityStaff.objects.get(id = request.data['id'])
            
            Staff.community=serializer.validated_data['community']
            Staff.role=serializer.validated_data['role']
            Staff.save()
            return Response({'detail': 'entry successfully'})
        else:
                    return Response({'error': 'unable to entry staff'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)                
    else:     
                return Response (serializer.data)
```

#error

File "C:\Users\Pinakee.Somyadarshee\Desktop\mykommunity\admindashboard\urls.py", line 2, in 
from admindashboard.views import Login_post,City_post,City_list,City_update,City_remove,Community_update,Community_list,Community_post,Community_detail,Admindash_list,Admindash_update,Admindash_remove,Admindash_post,Admindash_detail,Communitystaff
File "C:\Users\Pinakee.Somyadarshee\Desktop\mykommunity\admindashboard\views.py", line 11, in 
from admindashboard.serializers import CommunitysStaffSerializer
ImportError: cannot import name 'CommunitysStaffSerializer' from 'admindashboard.serializers' (C:\Users\Pinakee.Somyadarshee\Desktop\mykommunity\admindashboard\serializers.py)

Answer (score 0):

If serializers.py and views.py are in the same folder, use:

`from .serializers import CommunitysStaffSerializer`

Anyway, if you are using serializer.ModelSerailizer, you should define the model or, otherwise, you could use other serializer:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'CommunitysStaffSerializer' from 'admindashboard.serializers' (C:\Users\Pinakee.Somyadarshee\Desktop\mykommunity\admindashboard\serializers.py)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help without more information. Did you tried with the import I suggested?

Comment: several time i trying now its work properly. iserranoe please check my next question its urgent and help me out  .can i retrieve foreign key in serializers.py .Please check m next question

Comment: What is your next question?

Comment: retrieve data in multiple tables without procedure in function based view .Give me a example in django rest-framework

Comment: I'm sorry, but stack overflow doesn't work like that. You must post a question, showing clearly your problem and your code, and the rest of users will answer you if they know and can. You can't say in a comment "Give me an example".

Comment: ok, I'm already posted it.check it